# how null is checked in java?

Tags: java

I was working on some project and got a condition when I have to check the object is null or not from a list and all variables of the object are null.

So can someone explain to me how an object is checked for null i.e. variable wise or some other way.

how an object is checked for null internally in java don't want the code. want the concept

Please in a little detail.

My Question:   How Java internally checks if object contains a null value?

Comment: This is a google question, not really a programming question.

Comment: no no nothing like that.. i tried a lot on google but couldn't find anything so asked here..!!! and izZ acondition in my software..!!!

Comment: Please be more specific in your question then, because as it's worded, it seems you're asking for a method to check an object for null. Edit your question.

Comment: sure i'll do it..but can sumbody explain to me how any object is checked for null concept..

Comment: How in the world it's a duplicate?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, you are actually asking how `null` checks are implemented under the hood.

The answer is implementation specific. It could be different for different JVMs and / or execution platforms.  (If you want to research the specific implementation on a specific JVM, I suggest you checkout the JVM source code and/or get the JIT compiler to dump out the compiled native code for you to examine.)

Basically, there are two approaches:

- An explicit `x == null` test will typically compile to an instruction sequence that compares the value of `x` against the value that represents a `null`.  That is usually a 32-bit or 64-bit zero.
- The implicit null check in `x.toString()` could be done the same way.  Alternatively, it could be done by simply treating `x` as a machine address and attempting to fetch a value at that address.  Assuming that the zero page has not been mapped, this will trigger a hardware "segmentation fault" exception.  Java uses native code mechanisms to trap that exception, and turn it into a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Is it then possible to print a corresponding int value of null?

Comment: Not in regular Java.  But you don't need to.  See my suggestions about how to research the question.

Comment: A very good explanation ! The question isn't so bad for down-votes, but not represented correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking at a single item:

```
if(object == null)
{
   (...)
}
```

You mentioned a list. Let's pretend it's an ArrayList of Objects:

```
for(Object o : array_list)
{
   if(o == null)
   {
      (...)
   }
}
```

You'd also want to check to see if your list is null before you start looping through it.

Comment: you got me wrong!! i wanted to ask how java checks for null i.e. by checking if all variables of that are null or some other way?

Comment: @tushargarg unclear what are you asking .you should clarify more

Comment: izZ just that i want to know how an object is checked for null internally in java don't want the code. want the concept.

Answer (score 1):

Basically any can be easily checked for `null` value. Every internal details and implementations of `null` and comparison with `object` are totally managed by java so all we need is to have a compare of the `object` with `null` as :-

```
Object obj = null; // Object can be replaced with any class 
if(obj == null){
// do your logics
}
```

As far as any `List` or `Collection` is considered, to see if `object` stored in it are `null` or not :-

```
List <String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("hi");
list.add(null);
for(String s : list){
 if(s == null){
// do your logics here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java does not check if an object is a `"null"`.

You cannot have a `null` object as `null` does not extend the `Object` class.

What you can do in java is have a variable assigned to `null`, meaning it references "nothing". (In reality, it is referencing the bytes that `null` is defined as)

That is what the other answers are doing, they are checking if a reference variable is actually pointing to nothing (`null`). An object itself, however, is never `null`.

Comment: This is not helpful.  You are correct that the JLS says that `null` is not an object.  However, in reality Java professionals are happy to use the phrase "check an object for null" because we all know what it means ... to us.

Comment: @StephenC This is true. However, I was reading through some of OP's comments and in a few of them he asked if an object is null if "all variables are null .... [and] how an object is checked for null internally"

I interpreted this as wanting to know exact details, one of them being than object itself is not null, and that the variable is made to reference `null`, which is how we check if "an object is null"

Comment: I put that down to poor English skills ...

Comment: Fair enough. Guess we won't know what exactly OP wanted.

Comment: @Marcin you are correct i wanted to ask the same thing and very thanks but by the time you answered i found it.